# Imported MySQL data's superscript charactor not showing correctly in HTML page

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Currently I have a `XAMPP` server and `MySQL` database related to it. The database has some data that has superscript charactors such as ™. I used some form to insert such data into database. In database it has been showing as `â„¢`. But when I query, then it shows correctly as ™ in the `HTML` page.

**My Issue**

I created the same database in another `XAMPP` server and transferred data by exporting from original `MySQL` database and import to new `MySQL` database. All data transferred correctly. But this time, when I query the special charactor and showed in `HTML` page, it is not showing the superscript charactor as ™, instead it shows as `â„¢`.

When I export data, I used `utf-8` too

[image]

But when I tried to add a new data with ™ in it by using query into the new `MySQL` database and such added data is showing correctly as ™ instead of `â„¢`. But those imported data is still not showing correctly in `HTML` page.

I tried to add `mysqli_set_charset($conn,“utf8”)` in the connection file. But it is not solving the issue.

Does anyone know why this way?

Comment: There's a number of settings you'll need to align with `utf8`, or today, `utf8mb4` to support the full range of UTF-8 characters including emoji. 

Comment: If you're seeing ™ show up as multiple characters that's a sign that you're doing accidental 8-bit conversion somewhere in the process to Latin1 or Windows-1252.

Comment: @tadman But may i know why this issue happening only when I import the database, but not seeing if i create the data using query?

Comment: It's due to mismatched types somewhere. Maybe your importer is not on the same page. Possibly your front end is completely broken, but consistently broken, so you don't notice.